# Angular Js two way binding

Tags: angularjs

I have few text boxes and would like to implement the simple calculation like:

- Value of (TextBox1 + TextBox2 + textBox3) = Value of TextBox4.
- (TextBox4 + TextBox5)= value of TextBox6

How can achieve this in AngularJS?

See below for an example:

```
<table ng-app="" ng-controller="acadController">
<tr ng-repeat="x in semone">
            <td>{{ x.SubjectName }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.Credit }}</td>
            <td><input type="number" ng-model="pt1" /></td>
            <td><input type="number" ng-model="pt2"/></td>
            <td><input type="number" ng-model="ia"/></td>
            <td><input type="number" value="{{pt1+pt2+ia}}" ng-model="semMarks" class="marks_catotal" /></td>
            <td><input type="number" ng-model="endSemMarks" class="marks_endsem" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="marks_total" value="{{ semMarks + endSemMarks }}"/></td>
        </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: Thanks you guys for the kind help. I am not questioning any one ability here. however  all the below solutions are not working for me.
however when i have created a new solution and just added single line of Text fields, all the below solutions works.... but they are not working in my actulal solution...it might be because i am creating the rows dynamically ( see my original thread "<tr ng-repeat="x in semone">" )

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$watch` function to react to user changes :

Inside your controller, you can fire a function when a value is modified.

```
function calculateResult(){
    $scope.semMarks = $scope.pt1 + $scope.pt2 + $scope.ia;
}

$scope.$watch('pt1', calculateResult);
$scope.$watch('pt2', calculateResult);
```

Instead of your watch, you could also have registered a function that will be fired directly when you modify a value :

```
$scope.calculateResult = calculateResult;
```

And then, inside your view, you would just have to call this function when an input is modified.

```
<td><input type="number" ng-model="pt2" ng-change="calculateResult()"/></td>
```

Most of the time, using an event consumes less processor than using a $watch. Angular evaluates every `$watch` and check if there were any changes during each `$digest` cycle. Angulars uses also a lot of $watches itself, so adding too much $watches can significally decrease performances.

Answer (score 0):

You can use use $scope.watch to watch those variables and their sum and if it changes add it to $scope.marks

```
$scope.$watch('pt1 + pt2', function(v) {$scope.marks = v;});
```

See this plnkr: http://embed.plnkr.co/p0rQkUBMfEmYZkKh4Nrt/

Answer (score 0):

Consider [introducing a controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02) for `endSemMarks` and `marks_total`.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply bind to a function that evaluates the sum of the values. As mentioned above, $watch is more expensive and a little harder to understand.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.tb1 = 0;
  $scope.tb2 = 0;
  $scope.tb3 = 0;
  $scope.tb5 = 0;

  $scope.sum123 = function() {
    return $scope.tb1 + $scope.tb2 + $scope.tb3;
  }

  $scope.sum45 = function() {
    return $scope.tb1 + $scope.tb2 + $scope.tb3 + $scope.tb5;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  <div>1 :
    <input type="number" ng-model="tb1">
  </div>
  <div>2 :
    <input type="number" ng-model="tb2">
  </div>
  <div>3 :
    <input type="number" ng-model="tb3">
  </div>
  <div>4 :
    <input type="number" ng-value="sum123()">
  </div>
  <div>5 :
    <input type="number" ng-model="tb5">
  </div>
  <div>6 :
    <input type="number" ng-value="sum45()">
  </div>
</body>
```